# How to get the evidence of the email sent for weekly data export?

Tags: data-export, scheduled, backup

I configured the Weekly Data Export process logged in as another user with the proper permissions. Now such user is telling me that he didn´t received any email. I also have the data export configured with my user and I did receive the email. Is there any way of knowing if he actually received the email, any evidence or error log or whatever in order to be sure of what happened?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can track that with the use of **Email Logs**

Navigate: Monitoring -> Email Log files.

> Email logs describe all emails sent through salesforce.com and can be used to help identify the status of an email delivery. Email logs are CSV files that provide information such as the email address of each email sender and its recipient, the date and time each email was sent, and any error code associated with each email. Logs are only available for the past 30 days.

[image: Email logs]